# Paused Activity flashes Black on orientation change

Tags: android

In my Application I make the images clickable, and once they are clicked another Dialogue type Activity is launched which contains a larger version of the image. The problem is that the Paused activity in the back flashes black whenever the orientation is changed. It seems like it isnt animating its orientation change. Only the Paused Activity flashes black.

Here is the code for the running Activity.

```
public class ImageDialog extends Activity {

    private ImageView mDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.image_dialog);
        mDialog = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
        if (tabletSize) {
            // do something
        } else {
            int orientationMode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientationMode == 1) {
               changeViewPlease();
            }
        }




    }
    public void onScreenClickClose(View view) {
        finish();
    }
    public void changeViewPlease() {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

and the style being used:

```
      <style name="myDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">.8</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
```

the layout xml sheet:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_dialog_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onScreenClickClose" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image1largerotated" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: so if it's a phone you want the screen to always be landscape?

Comment: Yeah I want the Running Activity to be landscape on phones, dont really care what the Paused one is though.

Comment: The problem is that because you have a transparent background, the pasued activity might be destroyed, not entirely sure though. What happens if you don't call changeViewPlease() ? I'm just wondering cause you could make the activity load different layouts instead of loaing portrait first, and changing it programatically.

Comment: Yeah I think it is something like that. All changeViewPlease() does is force landscape and I actually took that out. I thought about doing the layouts, but is there a way to make it where orientation changes would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the Paused activity in the back flashes black
>   whenever the orientation is changed

This may happens because your background activity is destroyed and recreated again when orientation is changed. This is default behavior of an activity.

You can try this by avoiding recreation of background activity by handling `android:configChanges="orientation"` in AndroidManifest of your background activity tag.

You can give a try to this too.

Comment: I think that your answer is right AndroDev, I am gonna leave this open a few days just incase though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a half way solution, it still doesnt account for orientation changes after onCreate().

Add this to the paused Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
int orientationMode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientationMode == 1) {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

and android:screenOrientation="landscape" to the Manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".ImageDialog" android:theme="@style/myDialogTheme" 
   android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

I dont quite understand why this works!